# Google's OAuth2 login_hint parameter does not work with the sub identifier despite what the docs say?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm setting login_hint to a previously retrieved sub identifier (unique Google ID) as part of an authorization request url, but it doesn't select the appropriate account. It does do it if instead of the sub I supply the email address of that user.

According to Google's documentation however the sub identifier should also work:

> Optional. If your application knows which user is trying to
>   authenticate, it can use this parameter to provide a hint to the
>   Google Authentication Server. The server uses the hint to simplify the
>   login flow either by prefilling the email field in the sign-in form or
>   by selecting the appropriate multi-login session.
>
> Set the parameter value to an email address or sub identifier, which
>   is equivalent to the user's Google ID.

Any ideas how to get it working, or whether this is indeed a bug?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem when using `gapi.auth2.authorize` while the doc states `The email, or User ID, of a user to pre-select in the sign-in flow` (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authorizeconfig)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using the email now instead of the Google ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I opened a ticket even if I doubt Google will do anything https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/567

Comment: Cool - I commented on it in the off chance that it will make it more visible to them :)